# ¿Se puede pasar una función como parámetro en python?

Tags: python, funciones

Me pregunto si es posible usar una función como parámetro en otra funciona, así como: `def nombre_de_la_funcion(x)` recibe cualquier valor en Python, me gustaría saber si es posible  tener un parámetro que reciba cualquier función, algo como `def nombre_de_la_funcion(cualquier_funcion(n))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por supuesto, en general todos los datos en Python están representados por objetos o relaciones entre objetos. No hay nada particularmente especial en relación a las funciones, son objetos de primera clase y puedes asignarlas a otra variable, almacenarlas en un contenedor (lista, diccionario...), pasarlas como argumento, etc como cualquier otro objeto.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
def cuadrado(x):
    return x ** 2

def raiz_cuadrada(x):
    return x ** 0.5

def operar(func, *args):
    for n in args:
        print(func(n))
```

La función `operar` recibe como primer parámetro una función y un número indeterminado de argumentos que serán usados como argumentos de la función recibida:

```
>>> operar(cuadrado, 2, 3, 5)
4
9
25

>>> operar(raiz_cuadrada, 9, 25, 64, 49)
3.0
5.0
8.0
7.0
```

`operar(cuadrado)` no ejecuta la función en ningún momento, solo toma la referencia de la función `cuadrado` y crea un segundo nombre (`func`) apuntando a él. Si haces `foo(bar(x))` como muestras en la pregunta, no estas pasando como argumento la función `bar`, estas pasando su retorno ya que en este caso si que se ejecuta.

---

Una función no solo puede ser pasada como argumento, **también puede ser retornada por otra función**, de hecho esta es la idea de los decoradores precisamente:

```
def args_type_checking(fn):
    def wrapper(*args):   
        if all(isinstance(arg, (float, int)) for arg in args):
            return fn(*args)
        raise ValueError("Todos los argumentos deben ser enteros o floats")
    return wrapper
```

La función anterior toma como parámetro una función `fn` y la decora, crea un wrapper en torno a ella que, en este caso, comprueba si los parámetros pasados son todos enteros o float. Veamos como funciona decorando con la función anterior otra función que retorna la suma de un numero indeterminado de argumentos.

```
@args_type_checking
def suma(*args):
    print("La suma es: {}.".format(sum(args)))
```

Veamos lo que ocurre:

```
>>> suma(2, 8.5 ,6 ,7)
La suma es: 23.5.
>>> suma(2, 8.5 ,'4' ,7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    suma(2, 8.5 ,'4' ,7)
  File "D:\main.py", line 5, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Todos los argumentos deben ser enteros o floats")
ValueError: Todos los argumentos deben ser enteros o floats
```

---

Igualmente podemos almacenar las funciones (sus referencias propiamente dicho) en un contenedor como se comentaba, por ejemplo:

```
>>> funciones = {"c": cuadrado, 'rc': raiz_cuadrada}
>>> funciones["c"](5)
25
>>> funciones["rc"](81)
9.0
>>> funciones['c']
<function cuadrado at 0x000002763F83AE18>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu aporte, ha sido de gran ayuda, me ha quedado muy claro, gracias